# Fetch questions from offset?

Tags: support

I want to fetch questions from a certain offset. Not a minimum creation date, just an offset index, independent of the sort and order I'm using. How can I do this? Is it possible at all?

**Page/pagesize** are **NOT** suitable for me in this case, as I want to be able to pick an offset that is not dividable by the pagesize, too.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean an offset into questions ordered by `question_id`.  That begs a lot of questions, but...

You can convert between `question_id` and `creation_date` given the knowledge that `question_id` increases monotonically.  However, you can't guarantee the number of requests such an operation will take - though in practice more than 5 would be somewhat unusual*.

Make a query to `/questions/{id}` where `id` = desired offset, then make a request to `/questions?fromdate={startdate}&sort=creation&order=asc` where `startdate` = the creation date returned by the previous `/questions/{id}` query.  That will give you a set of questions from the desired offset ordered by `question_id`.  You can use `fromdate` to the same effect (minimum `question_id` to return) in most other queries.

The tricky part is if the question with the desired offset has been deleted, in which case you'll have to increment {id} until you find a subsequent question that has not.

<sub>*Such large gaps of deleted questions are indicative of periods of abuse that have been cleaned up subsequently.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer. However, I didn't mean questions ordered by `question_id`. I meant *any* order. I know it is possible to get the desired range of questions with a maximum of two requests with page/pagesize parameters. I just wondered if it would be possible in *one* request.

Comment: @eWolf - no.  You can fetch a set of ids using vectorized requests (`/questions/1;2;3;4;5;6` for example, up until the path grows too large to handle) but there is no way to restrict returned values by `question_id`.